# How to overwrite a worksheet with a dataframe using win32com

Tags: python, excel, dataframe, win32com

I'm working with a .xlsb file, hence the pandas seems not to work so I'm using win32com.
Let's say the file looks like this:

```py
import win32com.client as win32

xlApp = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
try:
    wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(filepath)
except:
    print('Could not open file')

wb_sheets = [sheet.Name for sheet in wb.Sheets]

wb_sheets
['Sheet1'],
'Sheet2']
```

How can I overwrite 'Sheet2' with an existing dataframe `mydf`?

After that step, is the following line the right way to save the file as a .xlsb?

```py
wb.SaveAs(Filename='newfile.xlsb', FileFormat=50) 
xlApp.Quit()
```

Comment: You could save your DataFrame to a temporary `.xlsx`, and open that. Then use `wb.Sheets['Sheet2'].UsedRange.Clear()` to get rid of the existing data, then copy the data from your temp book to Sheet2. How you do that last part will depend on whether your DataFrame includes any Style formatting. You can replace `FileFormat=50` with `FileFormat = win32.constants.xlExcel12` to make it more readable.